# Can restaurants charge differently based on customer's language?

Tags: discrimination, payment, food, language, restaurants

I greeted some Chinese friends who just arrived at an airport. They were hungry after a long flight so we ate lunch inside the airport. We sat down and opened the menu in Chinese. We ordered some food and talked about our lives. While one was patting another on the back, he accidentally touched the display and changed the language of the menu to French. I noticed something strange. I felt some of the prices changing.

To confirm my sense I went through all the languages available. They were English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, Portugese, Dutch, Chinese(Traditional), Chinese(Simplified) and Japanese. Only the two Chinese languages served different prices from the others. In the Chinese menu water was $1.50 while it was free in other menus. Other drinks were also a dollar more expensive on average. The dishes were priced the same.

I immediately stood up and protested. Eventually a manager came out and apologized for the price discrepancy, claiming it was "a technical issue". They did give us a refund for the extra costs incurred but we were pissed and decided never to go there again.

Can restaurants get away with this kind of discriminatory behavior by deliberately overcharging people who speak a minority language and explain that there was "a technical issue" every time this is brought up? Is there any legislation/provision/etc. that prevents such malicious action?

Comment: In which country did this happen?

Answer (score -3):

It can be a "technical issue" once. Once you left, the restaurant would be aware of the "technical issue", and if anyone orders from the Chinese menu before the "technical issue" is resolved, they will reduce the price without having to be prompted. They will also resolve the "technical issue" as soon as possible.

If they don't, then it will be illegal discrimination.

Comment: Except that resolving such a "technical issue" will certainly take a year or two...

Comment: As I said, in that case it is illegal discrimination. In the UK, if a shop advertises an item at too low a price, they can refuse to sell it and claim it was a mistake. If you want it, you return two hours later. If it's still the low price, you'll either get the item, or you tell them that you will call trading standards and get the item, or you have to call trading standards and they'll wish they had sold at the lower price.

Comment: Unlawful where and how? Something as fundamental as [gender-based pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladies%27_night) is not always illegal. Price discrimination based on occupation (student discount) or age (senior discount) is widespread.

Comment: I think the question should specify a jurisdiction, but I think this answer also needs a jurisdiction. It's hard to believe that this is true in every jurisdiction. It would also be nice if there was some citation for the claim that this is illegal discrimination